# C# More intuitive way to split a string into tokens?

Tags: c#, string, token

I have a method which takes in a string, which contains various characters, but I'm only concerned about underscores '_' and dollar signs '$'. I want to split up the string into tokens by underscores as each piece b/w the underscores contains important information.

However, if a $ is contained in an area between underscores, then a token should be created from the last occurrence of an underscore to the end (ignoring any underscores in this last section).

**Example**

input: Hello_To_The$Great_World

expected tokens: Hello, To, The$Great_World

**Question**

I have a solution below, but I'm wondering is there a cleaner/more intuitive way of doing this than what I have below?

```
var aTokens = new List<string>();
var aPos = 0;
for (var aNum = 0; aNum < item.Length; aNum++)
{
    if (aNum == item.Length - 1)
    {
        aTokens.Add(item.Substring(aPos, item.Length - aPos));
        break;
    }               
    if (item[aNum] == '$')
    {
        aTokens.Add(item.Substring(aPos, item.Length - aPos));
        break;
    }
    if (item[aNum] == '_')
    {
    aTokens.Add(item.Substring(aPos, aNum - aPos));
    aPos = aNum + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean ->However, if a $ is contained in an area between underscores, then a token should be created from the [Previous] occurrence of an underscore to the end (ignoring any underscores in this last section).

Comment: @IllidanS4 I guess it is `between`.

Comment: @JasonHernandez good point! The underscores should only appear after the $ I believe though

Comment: @IllidanS4 between, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split string by `_` not having `$` before them.

For that you can use the following regex:

```
(?<!\$.*)_
```

Sample code:

```
string input = "Hello_To_The$Great_World";
string[] output = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<!\$.*)_");
```

You also can do the task without regex and without loops, but with the help of 2 splits:

```
string input = "Hello_To_The$Great_World";
string[] temp = input.Split(new[] { '$' }, 2);
string[] output = temp[0].Split('_');
if (temp.Length > 1)
    output[output.Length - 1] = output[output.Length - 1] + "$" + temp[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This method is not efficient or clean, but it gives you a general idea of how to do this:

1. Split your string into tokens
2. Find the index of the first string to contain $
3. Return a new array with the first n tokens and the final token is the remaining strings concatenated.

It's probably more useful to take advantage of IEnumerable or do things over a for loop instead of all this Array.Copy stuff... but you get the gist of it.

```
private string[] SomeMethod(string arg)
{
    var strings = arg.Split(new[] { '_' });

    var indexedValue = strings.Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i }).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Contains("$"));

    if (indexedValue != null)
    {
        var count = indexedValue.Index + 1;

        string[] final = new string[count];
        Array.Copy(strings, 0, final, 0, indexedValue.Index);
        final[indexedValue.Index] = String.Join("_", strings, indexedValue.Index, strings.Length - indexedValue.Index);
        return final;
    }

    return strings;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version (loops are *so* last year...)

```
const char dollar = '$';
const char underscore = '_';

var item = "Hello_To_The$Great_World";
var aTokens = new List<string>();

int dollarIndex = item.IndexOf(dollar);
if (dollarIndex >= 0)
{
    int lastUnderscoreIndex = item.LastIndexOf(underscore, dollarIndex);
    if (lastUnderscoreIndex >= 0)
    {
        aTokens.AddRange(item.Substring(0, lastUnderscoreIndex).Split(underscore));
        aTokens.Add(item.Substring(lastUnderscoreIndex + 1));
    }
    else
    {
        aTokens.Add(item);
    }
}
else
{
    aTokens.AddRange(item.Split(underscore));
}
```

**Edit:**

I should have added, cleaner/more intuitive is very subjective, as you have found out by the variety of answers provided. From a maintainability point of view, it's much more important that the method you write to do the parsing is unit tested!

It's also an interesting exercise to test the performance of the various methods posted here - it quickly becomes apparent that your original version is much faster than using regular expressions! (Although in a real life situation, it's probably quite unlikely that the performance of this method will make any difference to your application!)

Comment: It's nice to see a non-looping version though! nice